# form action not called only in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

With the following form in my HTML user can go to another Site.

```
<form id="fr"  method="post" action="otherWall.do">                 
    <a href="otherWall.html" onclick="parentNode.submit();">go to Site</a> 
    <input type="hidden" name="friend" value="42"/>
</form>
```

In Firefox and Opera, the `action="otherWall.do"` is called which in turn redirects to `otherWall.html`, but when I open the page in Chrome, the `action="otherWall.do"` is not called and it immediately goes to `otherWall.html`.

Do I have to consider some special approach in Chrome?

Comment: What language/framework/etc is this?

Comment: I work with Java with jsp and Servlets.  I already mentioned that in my origin post but it was shortened by someone...

Comment: Because that's irrelevant to the concrete problem. You just forgot to block HTML `<a>` element's default behavior in JavaScript. You'd still have had exactly the same problem when using any other server side language processing the HTTP POST request, such as PHP, ASP, Python, etc. The problem is just basic HTML/JS, apparently Joe himself is also not very well versed with basic HTML/JS and somehow thought it to be relevant in order to reproduce the concrete problem.